# how to serve same app content differently for different domains using angular and firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

Is it possible to use multiple domains with firebase running in the background with the same application and database for each and every domain?. What I mean by this is that we want to be able to build the same system for our clients but on their separate domains.

The goal is to have a server side application running all the same backend-logic with multiple websites and with angular change the front-end components depending on what domain the user visits.

I'm not able to find any information about this other than using multiple applications with the same domain. This is not what I aim to do.

Thanks and I hope this is appropriate to ask in this forum, otherwise please do let me know where I can find more information about this.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has something known as environment file, where you can know the domain by:

```
let url = location.origin
```

Now you can import this file in your app component and check for url. For ex:

```
url === 'https://example.com'
```

and use component based on url.

NOTE: The environment file is generally used based on environment. For ex one can have different environment file for production mode.